# Remove a part of string before underscore

Tags: r, gsub

I have a character vector of names that look like

```
A00_A09_Intestinal_infectious_diseases
A09_Diarrhoea_and_gastro_enteritis
```

I would like to remove the IDs on the beginning of string, so that it would look like

```
Intestinal_infectious_diseases
Diarrhoea_and_gastro_enteritis
```

I suppose it is possible to be done with `gsub` but due to my small experience, it didnt work out for me.
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can try with `sub`.  Match zero or more characters followed by a capital letter followed by one or more numbers and a underscore and replace it with `""`.

```
sub(".*[A-Z][0-9]+_", "", str1)
#[1] "Intestinal_infectious_diseases" "Diarrhoea_and_gastro_enteritis"
```

Or to be specific, we match the pattern of one or more instances of (`{1,}`) capital letter (`[A-Z]`) followed by one or more numbers (`[0-9]+`) followed by an underscore (`_`) and replace it with blank (`""`).

```
sub("([A-Z][0-9]+_){1,}", "", str1)
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("A00_A09_Intestinal_infectious_diseases", "A09_Diarrhoea_and_gastro_enteritis")
```